# How to map Array of EventLoopFuture<Type> to Array of EventLoopFuture<OtherType> in Vapor

Tags: swift, future, vapor

I have a Vapor backend that I wrote a few tests for.

The test code looks like this:

```swift
    func testFollowUser() throws {
        user = try user.save(on: conn).wait()

        let userToFollow = try User(firstName: "Friedrich", lastName: "Nietzsche", email: "f.nietzsche@gmail.com", passwordHash: User.TestValues.passwordHash).save(on: conn).wait()

        let req = UserListRequest(ids: [userToFollow.id!])

        XCTAssert(try user.followers.query(on: conn).count().wait() == 0)
        XCTAssert(try userToFollow.followees.query(on: conn).count().wait() == 0)

        let res = try app.sendRequest(to: "/me/following", method: .PUT, body: req, isLoggedInRequest: true)

        //sleep(4)

        XCTAssert(res.http.status == .noContent, "Returned \(res.http.status)")
        XCTAssert(try user.followers.query(on: conn).count().wait() == 1)
        XCTAssert(try userToFollow.followees.query(on: conn).count().wait() == 1)
        XCTAssert(try user.followers.query(on: conn).first().wait()?.id == userToFollow.id)

        _ = userToFollow.delete(on: conn)
    }
```

(The sendRequest(to:method:body:isLoggedInRequest) waits for the request to finish using .wait())

And the function beeing tested looks like this:

```swift
    func followUsers(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<HTTPStatus> {
        let user = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
        return try req.content.decode(UserListRequest.self).flatMap { userListRequest -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> in
            userListRequest.ids.map { idToFollow -> EventLoopFuture<User?> in
                return User.find(idToFollow, on: req)
            }.flatten(on: req).map {
                maybeUsersToFollow -> Future<[FollowPivot]> in
                var futureArray: [Future<FollowPivot>] = []
                for maybeUserToFollow in maybeUsersToFollow {
                    if let userToFollow = maybeUserToFollow {
                        let pivot = try FollowPivot(user, userToFollow).save(on: req)
                        futureArray.append(pivot)
                    }
                }
                return futureArray.flatten(on: req)
            }.transform(to: req.future(HTTPStatus(statusCode: 204)))
        }
    }
```

When I execute the test it fails. If I add "sleep(4)" in the test method the tests passes. I therefore assume, that the Postgres operation within the database is not finished when the XCTAssert is executed.

I changed the function code above to:

```swift
    func followUsers(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<HTTPStatus> {
        let user = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
        return try req.content.decode(UserListRequest.self).flatMap { userListRequest -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> in
            userListRequest.ids.map { idToFollow -> EventLoopFuture<User?> in
                return User.find(idToFollow, on: req)
            }.map { maybeUserToFollowFuture -> Future<Void> in
                maybeUserToFollowFuture.then {
                    maybeUserToFollow in
                    if let userToFollow = maybeUserToFollow {
                        do {
                            return try FollowPivot(user, userToFollow)
                                .save(on: req)
                                .transform(to: req.future())
                        } catch {}
                    }
                    return req.future()
                }
            }.flatten(on: req)
            .transform(to: req.future(HTTPStatus(statusCode: 204)))
        }
    }
```

The test now succeeds, but in my opinion the code is rather bad.

How do I properly process an `[EventLoopFuture<Type>]` to `[EventLoopFuture<OtherType>]` while guaranteeing that succeeding map transformation operations are only executed after all the futures within the array have been fulfilled? 
Why does my first `followUser(on:)` not work properly? Do I need an explicit `.then()` operation to guarantee fulfillment?

Comment: If you don't get a response here, you might have more luck on Discord (https://discord.gg/vapor)

Comment: @Chris I have done that. Thank you. I sadly still have no proper answer.